# Populate Dropdownlists from existing data on update with MANY_MANY relation

Tags: yii, many-to-many

I Have two tables related MANY_MANY with a joining table.

The CarGroup model shows this relation

```
'carModels' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'CarModel', 'car_model_car_group_assignment(car_group_id, car_model_id)')
```

My create and update actions in the view  _form.php have three added dropdownlists to select the data from the CarModel table similar to this:-

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'carModels',CHtml::listData(CarModel::model()->active()->findAll(),'id','title'))
```

My Question is how do I populate the dropdownlists with the saved selections when doing an update?

Comment: what model do you want to use? do you want to use the joining table model?

Answer (score 0):

So you have `CarGroup` and `CarModel` related MANY_MANY.  You want the _form.php for `CarGroup` to have three dropdowns to relate a `CarGroup` model to...what exactly?  Why wouldn't you have a single multi-select that allows adding/removing multiple `CarModel`s to the `CarGroup` model being updated?  If you add a little more detail someone might be able to help.